# add more spheres in a circle

Tags: modeling

I have 40 spheres in one circle but I want to add 2 more spheres in a circle how do I do this in a blender?[image]

Comment: Where did you get this model from? If the question was: "How do I create a circle of n touching spheres", then there could be multiple easy answers: an array modifier with a rotated empty offset, a screw modifier on a vertex and instancing, resampling a circle curve in geometry nodes, or just outside of geometry nodes defining a resolution of a bezier circle and instancing... However if you're starting in a model and need to edit it, it will depend on the model...

Comment: since this is an absolute easy model and quickly to recreate as Markus already described, i would recommend making it totally new instead of wasting time by "improving" the old one, which takes more time

Answer (score 1):

**If** the marbles/pearls have **all the same size** and if they **are not merged** in your model, you can separate them by loose parts in *Edit* mode. Select everything (<kbd>A</kbd>), separate (<kbd>P</kbd>), and move the marbles into their own collection (<kbd>M</kbd>). Delete the duplicates.

Now you can do a bit math to calculate the radius of the new circle. The formula for the circumference of a circle is $= 2*pi*r$.

$n$ marbles with a diameter of $s$ have the length = $n*s$.

This then gives the equation:
$2*pi*r = n * s$

Resolved by r, results:
$r = (n*s) / (2*pi)$

Now you have everything for a "marble circle" generator in *Geometry Nodes*. Add a plane or cube (it's just a dummy object) and give it this *Geometry Nodes* modifier:

[image: marble circle generator]

Enter the values for the circle in the modifier settings. In the side panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) of the GN editor, you can change the names and types of the group input slots. These are the settings of the modifier.

Note that you can enter `pi` and `2*pi` in the text boxes of the nodes and Blender will resolve it to `3.14159` and `6.28319`, respectively.

If you want to run a *Cloth* simulation to create a pearl necklace you need a *Realize Instances* node at the end of the node tree. And maybe a *Set Material* node.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation!